# Short (horror) story about about a guy with an implant that lets him turn off his conscious mind

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, horror

I'm trying to find a short story about a guy with a sort of p-zombie implant that lets him like, turn off his consciousness or something like that, which he uses to be more productive at work. Except that one day it breaks and he finds out his workplace is some sort of fucked up rich person's sex dungeon.

At the end he runs off and goes home and finds out his wife has been using the implant, because I guess being married to him is so intolerable that she'd rather be unconscious for it or something like that.

Comment: Welcome to the site. When did you read this story, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, where did you find it; in a mazine? Anthology? Online?